# Caught SyntaxError while rendering: invalid syntax

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am creating an django app 'cms' with django1.1 via 《Python Web Development with Django》. And I`m getting an "TemplateSyntaxError" error while accessing admin page.

Here's the traceback:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/
Caught SyntaxError while rendering: invalid syntax (views.py, line 18)
Request Method: GET
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Caught SyntaxError while rendering: invalid syntax (views.py, line 18)
Exception Location: D:\Program Files\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py          in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  D:\Program Files\python\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

my views.py are :

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.db.models import Q
from cms.models import Story, Category
from markdown import markdown
def category(request, slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug = slug)
    story_list = Story.objects.filter(category=category)
    heading = "Category: %s " % category.label
    return render_to_response("cms/story_list.html", locals())
def search(request):
    if "q" in request.GET:
        term = request.GET['q']
        story_list = Story.objects.filter(Q(title__contains=term) | (markdown_content__contains=term))
        heading = "Search results"
    return render_to_response("cms/story_list.html", locals())
```

Line 18 is 
    story_list = Story.objects.filter(Q(title__contains=term) | (markdown_content__contains=term))

And urls.py in cms:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from cms.models import Story

info_dict = {'queryset': Story.objects.all(), 'template_object_name': 'story' }

urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.list_detail',
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', info_dict, name="cms-story"),
    url(r'^$', 'object_list', info_dict, name='cms-home'),
)
urlpatterns += patterns('cmsproject.cms.views',
    url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'category', name="cms-category"),
    url(r'^search/$', 'search', name="cms-search"),             
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small typo on line 18, where you're missing the Q class on the second filter:

It should read:

```
story_list = Story.objects.filter(Q(title__contains=term) | Q(markdown_content__contains=term))
```